# Recupera valor do input e comparar com valor em jquery

Tags: javascript, jquery

Tenho esse código que recupera o valor digitado no input e compara com um valor x, nesse caso 25,00.
O problema é que quando mudo de campo dentro do form ele mostra o erro dizendo que o valor digitado é menor do que 25, porém se a pessoa nao corrigir e submeter o form ele envia assim mesmo, eu preciso que se o valor digitado for menor que 25 ele mostre a mensagem de erro e quando o usuário submeter o form ele volte a mostrar o erro não deixando o formulário seguir e quando o usuário digitar o valor correto, ou seja 25 ou maior, a mensagem de erro desapareça.

```
<div class="donate_amount_field m-0">
     <input type="text" name="amount" class="form-control" value="" required>
 </div>                                
 <div class="alert" id="error_amount" style="display: none;">valor menor que 25</div>


 $('input[name=amount]').blur(function() {

    if ( $(this).val() < "25,00" )

       showError_amount();

  });

  function showError_amount() {

     $("#error_amount").show();

  }
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```js
$('input[name=amount]').focusout(function() {
    var valorDigitado = parseFloat($(this).val());
    if (valorDigitado < 25) {
       $('input[name="amount"]').val(25.00);
       showError_amount();
       } else {
        $("#error_amount").hide();
       }
       
  });

  function showError_amount() {
     $("#error_amount").show();
  }
```

```html
<link href="https://stackpath.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.4.1/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet"/>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<form>
<div class="donate_amount_field m-0">
     <input type="text" name="amount" class="form-control" value="" placeholder="Valor Maior que 25.00" required>
 </div>                                
 <div class="alert alert-danger mt-3" role="alert" id="error_amount" style="display: none;"><strong>Atenção!</strong> Valor menor que 25!</div>
 </form>
```

**Veja se isso ajuda!**
Como uma solução rápida, eu simplesmente atribuo "automaticamente" o valor 25 dentro do input, caso o valor digitado pelo usuário seja menor que 25, entendeu?

Espero ter te ajudado! Qualquer dúvida só é falar ;)

Comment: Sua ajuda foi de grande valia, mas faltou um detalhe que esqueci de falar, o campo em questão ele tem uma mascara que formata o valor em real brasileiro 0,00 dai quando digito um valor mesmo com a mascara ele mostra a mensagem de erro dizendo que o valor é menor e coloca 25 no campo e é ai que esta o problema, ele coloca o valor 25 mas nao fica no formato 25,00, assim se um usuario nao corrigir ele vai mandar no formato que o codigo coloca que é 25 e assim vai dar erro na requisição é o que faltou esse valor estar no formato 25,00, tem como deixar assim, eu tentei mudar aqui mas nao deu.

Comment: Entendi.. faz o seguinte. Copia aqui todo html e js que vc tiver (incluindo essa questão da máscara), porque fica melhor de nós entendermos e poder te ajudar da melhor forma, tranquilo?

Comment: André muito obrigado, pela ajuda, eu ja consegui resolver, apenas coloquei essa parte do codigo  $('input[name="amount"]').val(25.00); onde esta o 25.00 mudei como string e coloquei entre "25,00", assim funcionou perfeitamente. Mais uma vez obrigado.

Comment: Show brother. Fico feliz que tenha conseguido sucesso! Abração.